# CakePhp 2.x Routing doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, routes, router

I have this link: localhost/issoisso/categories/getCategories/categoryId:486

but I need this: localhost/issoisso/categoria/486

the code is here:

[gist.github.com/kleberksms/7756990](https://gist.github.com/kleberksms/7756990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way...

```
    Router::connect('/categoria/:categoryId', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'getCategories'), array(
    'pass' => array('categoryId'),
    'categoryId' => '[0-9]+'
));
```